# Calculating full text string between two joined tables in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator

Using ArcMap 10.2.2, I performed a basic table join between a few of our electric feature classes to update the "Line and Pole" field with the attributes in the "Fuse Size" and "Fuse Type" fields.

We actually noticed multiple problems.

- First, a string like "25 Amps" (from the "Fuse Size" field) came across as "25", leaving off "Amps" - this occurred with all records.
- Also, for the "Fuse Type" value, "Load Break" was abbreviated and populated as "LB".

Both field types are strings. We went in and corrected the syntax manually.
But, any ideas as to why these scenarios occurred?

We haven't been able to find much after researching the problem.

Comment: are they text value domain fields?